# Why does reducing the number of loops not speed up the program?

Tags: java, performance, matrix-multiplication

I have a program that does a lot of matrix multiplication. I thought I'd speed it up by reducing the number of loops in the code to see how much faster it would be (I'll try a matrix math library later). It turns out it's not faster at all. I've been able to replicate the problem with some example code. My guess was that testOne() would be faster than testTwo() because it doesn't create any new arrays and because it has a third as many loops. On my machine, its takes twice as long to run:

> Duration for testOne with 5000 epochs: 657, loopCount: 64000000
>
> Duration for testTwo with 5000 epochs: 365, loopCount: 192000000

My guess is that `multOne()` is slower than `multTwo()` because in `multOne()` the CPU is not writing to sequential memory addresses like it is in `multTwo()`. Does that sound right? Any explanations would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayTest {

    double[] arrayOne;
    double[] arrayTwo;
    double[] arrayThree;

    double[][] matrix;

    double[] input;
    int loopCount;

    int rows;
    int columns;

    public ArrayTest(int rows, int columns) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.loopCount = 0;
        arrayOne = new double[rows];
        arrayTwo = new double[rows];
        arrayThree = new double[rows];
        matrix = new double[rows][columns];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = random.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }

    public void testOne(double[] input, int epochs) {
        this.input = input;
        this.loopCount = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration;
        for (int i = 0; i < epochs; i++) {
            multOne();
        }
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Duration for testOne with " + epochs + " epochs: " + duration + ", loopCount: " + loopCount);
    }

    public void multOne() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                arrayOne[i] += matrix[i][j] * arrayOne[i] * input[j];
                arrayTwo[i] += matrix[i][j] * arrayTwo[i] * input[j];
                arrayThree[i] += matrix[i][j] * arrayThree[i] * input[j];
                loopCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void testTwo(double[] input, int epochs) {

        this.loopCount = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration;
        for (int i = 0; i < epochs; i++) {
            arrayOne = multTwo(matrix, arrayOne, input);
            arrayTwo = multTwo(matrix, arrayTwo, input);
            arrayThree = multTwo(matrix, arrayThree, input);
        }
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Duration for testTwo with " + epochs + " epochs: " + duration + ", loopCount: " + loopCount);
    }

    public double[] multTwo(double[][] matrix, double[] array, double[] input) {
        double[] newArray = new double[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                newArray[i] += matrix[i][j] * array[i] * input[j];
                loopCount++;
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 100;
        int columns = 128;
        ArrayTest arrayTest = new ArrayTest(rows, columns);
        Random random = new Random();
        double[] input = new double[columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            input[i] = random.nextDouble();
        }
        arrayTest.testOne(input, 5000);
        arrayTest.testTwo(input, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Benchmarking in Java is _really, really, hard._  I would not trust your measurements -- it's really easy to write benchmarks that tell you the opposite of the truth.  Use JMH or the like if you want reliable data.

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started on answering it yourself (though it is nice to see a well made question): Change mult1 to use new arrays instead of `arrayOne +=`, `arrayTwo +=`, and `arrayThree +=`, then assign `arrayOne`, `arrayTwo`, and `arrayThree` at the end of the method.

Comment: That is probably true.

Comment: It'd be helpful to track the *time taken* instead of the operations performed. You can `System.nanotime()` to get the current time and then subtract the difference once your operations are over.

Comment: Yes , calculate time in nanosec.

Comment: In java , each loop instructions take nearly 1 cpu cycle computing time which is nearly 0.1nanosec. So by reducing the loops will definitely speedup the total time taken. Difficult to get the changes in milli second . so try to get the time taken in nanosec.

Comment: It seems to me `multOne` and `multTwo` don't do the same thing. Pls see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple reason why your tests take different time: *they don't do the same thing*. Since the two loops you compare are not functionally identical, the number of iterations is not a good metric to look at.

`testOne` takes longer than `testTwo` because:

- In `multOne` you update `arrayOne[i]` in place, during each iteration
  of the `j` loop. This means for each iteration of the inner loop `j`
  you are using *a new value* of `arrayOne[i]`, computed in the
  previous iteration. This creates a loop carried dependency, which is
  harder to optimise for the compiler, because you require the output
  of the operation `matrix[i][j] * arrayOne[i] * input[j]` on the next
  CPU clock cycle. This is not really possible with floating point
  operations, which have a  latency of a few clock cycles usually, so
  it results in stalls, therefore reduced performance.
- In `testTwo` you
  update `arrayOne` only once per each iteration of the `epoch`, and
  since there are no carried dependecies, the loop can be vectorised
  efficiently, which results in better cache and arithmetic
  performance.